# How am I improperly exporting fbx rig?

Tags: rigging, transforms, .fbx

When I export my fbx rig animation I get strange unwanted scaling and rotation transforms.

This is the animation in Blender
[image: desired animated rig/mesh in Blender]
[image: export settings] [image: export settings2]

When importing into Unreal Engine the animation does not appear like in Blender. [image: Appearance of animation in Unreal Engine]

I heard advice to scale the Blender world to 0.01 then 100x scale the mesh/rig and then apply all transforms to get it to work in Unreal.

[image: changing scale of Blender world] [image: scaling up mesh/rig 100x]

When I finally apply the scale transform to the 100x scaled up model still within Blender during this aforementioned process, I get strange distorted transforms.
[image: before applying transforms]
[image: after applying transforms]
It appears like the mesh is being further scaled up another 100x somehow but only on one axis? I haven't found a way around this to test if applying these transforms correctly will fix the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added screenshots with some annotations, hopefully it is more clear now!